# Not addind one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I hava class

```
class Read(models.Model):
   class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'reads'

   id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True);
   owner_reader = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_reader', null=False, blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)  # тот, кто прочитал
   articles_readed = models.ManyToManyField(Article, null=False, related_name='articles_readed')  # те, на кого он пдписалса
```

And want adding article to read item:

```
def mark_readed(request,id):
    #id -article id
    user =request.user # подписант
    try:
        reader1 = Read.objects.get(name='test',owner_reader=request.user)  
    except Read.DoesNotExist:
        reader1 = Read.objects.create(name='test',owner_reader=request.user)
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=id) 
    reader1.articles_readed.add=article
    reader1.save();
    return main(request)
```

But in result I have only readed item wisout articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, you are trying to add an article to the "articles_readed" many to many field.

Per django's documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), you should be associating the read object with the article using the `add()` method.

Thus, you should replace `reader1.articles_readed.add=article` with `reader1.articles_readed.add(article)`. Additionally, you shouldn't need to call the read `save()` method after adding the article.

Hope this helps!